# my centos X server stop working

Tags: linux, x-server

I have installed centos 7 with gnome desktop, today I installed lightdm and xfce, then I uninstalled some gnome packages except gnome-shell. then the system gui quit immediately. reboot leads  to a black screen. the Xserver log says:
cannot find file "default" for symbols include.

how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl + alt + f1 to get to the getty and log in the system.

I'd suggest to install group gnome as described here to get back missing packages:

https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-install-gnome-gui-in-centos-7-linux/